# What if i assign a const to a var?

Tags: dart

I tried to run this code

```
var a = const [1, 2, 3];
  a.add(10);
  print(a);
```

but I am having an error. As I knew that assigning and const to a variable doesn't make it a const.
So why is this error occurring?

> Unhandled exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an
> unmodifiable list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables in Dart is always references and the type of the variable does not change the state of the object it points to.

So in your case, you have declared a `const` list which means it is a compile-constant defined list and is therefore implicit unmodifiable.

You now point to this list by using a normal variable. But the type of the variable does not change the fact that your `List` is created as `const` from the beginning.